# understanding how prop() is used when dealing with child elements(rather than properties)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got this snippet online, it basically is a jQuery function that accepts a index value and than on page load loads that particular `option` value into the input field. Have a look at the snippet:

**HTML::**

```
<input type="text" id="city" name="city" list="clist" placeholder="Select City">
<datalist id="clist" name="clist">
    <option value="10th mile">15094</option>
    <option value="A.s.peta">2958</option>
    <option value="Faizpur">7313</option>
    <option value="Gabbar">7480</option>
    <option value="Gadag">7227</option>
    <option value="Hadpid">6474</option>
</datalist>
```

**jQuery**

```
$.fn.datalistOptionSet = function (index) {
    return this.each(function () {
        var input = $(this)
        var list = $("#" + input.attr("list"))
        var options = $($(list).prop("options"))
        input.val(options.eq(index).val())
    })
}
$("#city").datalistOptionSet(0);
```

**[FIDDLE HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/jakecigar/7mga0hvt/)**

My question is about the below line of code :

```
var options = $($(list).prop("options"));
```

I understand how `prop()` works , but really in this example how is `option` a property of `datalist`, its a child element , not a property right ? also why the plural `.prop("options")` , `options` instead of `option` ? the plural confuses me, because i don't see any HTML element with the tag name of `options` .

Can anybody answer these two questions of mine.

Comment: Options is a property of a select list. It contains all option elements associated with the list... However I must add most of that code is redundant to be done with jquery.

Comment: @rlemon you meant datalist ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using

```
var options = $($(list).prop("options"))
```

You could just do:

```
var options = $(list).children();
```

Seems a lot easier to read.

As for the question about properties...don't forget that the dom is an object and elements are objects. Your wondering about `options` being a property of the list isn't any different than a form element having properties that relate to  the controls within it